# Finding a value in a dataframe according to two columns from another data frame with R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe with two specific columns (weight and country) for each order. I have another dataframe giving all the possible combinations for weight and  country, and their cost.

I want to create a new column at the first data frame that gives the cost for each case.

This is what I tried, but i gives me a column for each country according to the weight.

```
df1$cost <- df2[df1$weight,df1$country]
```

Comment: `help("merge")`

Comment: But still, merge gives me one new column for each country. I would like to have only one new column with the costs by country and weight

Comment: I think your data structure is not clear to me. You should provide a minimal reproducible example if you expect useful answers. It might be necessary to reshape one of your data.frames.

Comment: Please add such information to the question (there is an *edit*  link below it), where proper formatting is possible.

Comment: df1
+--------+---------+--------+--+
| client | country | weight |  |
+--------+---------+--------+--+
| a      | BE      |      3 |  |
| b      | FR      |      4 |  |
| c      | GE      |      4 |  |
+--------+---------+--------+--+
df2:
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
| Weight | BE  | FR  | GE  |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|      3 | 1.1 | 0.8 | 1.3 |
|      4 | 1.3 | 1.7 | 2.3 |
|     5  | 2.2 | 2.6 | 3.5 |
+--------+-----+-----+-----+

Comment: And the result:
Result:
+--------+---------+--------+------+
| client | country | weight | cost |
+--------+---------+--------+------+
| a      | BE      |      3 |  1.1 |
| b      | FR      |      4 |  1.7 |
| c      | GE      |      4 |  2.3 |
+--------+---------+--------+------+

Comment: Hi Miquel, its easier to help if you edit your question to add the dataframes. Run `dput` and paste the code for `df1`, `df2` and the expected output `df`.  For example `dput(head(df1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your df2 is in wide format and the weight variable has a different capitalization so you need to solve those before merge will work, try this...

```r
library(tidyr)
df2 <- 
   tidyr::pivot_longer(df2, -Weight, names_to = "country", values_to = "cost")

names(df2)[names(df2) == "Weight"] <- "weight"

df2
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   weight country  cost
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1      3 BE        1.1
#> 2      3 FR        0.8
#> 3      3 GE        1.3
#> 4      4 BE        1.3
#> 5      4 FR        1.7
#> 6      4 GE        2.3
#> 7      5 BE        2.2
#> 8      5 FR        2.6
#> 9      5 GE        3.5

merge(df1, df2)
#>   country weight client cost
#> 1      BE      3      a  1.1
#> 2      FR      4      b  1.7
#> 3      GE      4      c  2.3
```

Your data

```r
df1 <- data.frame( client = c("a","b","c"),
                   country = c("BE", "FR", "GE"),
                   weight = c(3, 4,4)
)
df1
#>   client country weight
#> 1      a      BE      3
#> 2      b      FR      4
#> 3      c      GE      4
df2 <- data.frame(
   Weight = c(3, 4, 5),
   BE = c(1.1, 1.3, 2.2),
   FR = c(0.8, 1.7, 2.6),
   GE = c(1.3, 2.3, 3.5)
)
df2
#>   Weight  BE  FR  GE
#> 1      3 1.1 0.8 1.3
#> 2      4 1.3 1.7 2.3
#> 3      5 2.2 2.6 3.5
```